# How to mock values of constant in tested function

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have a problem with mocking constant in my test. I have a file with app configuration. There are just keys with some values nothing more.

**appConfig.js**

```
//imports
 ...
 export const CASHING_AMOUNT_LIMIT = 50;
 export const CASHING_DELETE_AMOUNT = 25;
 ...
```

and this is the reducer that I want to test:

**reducer.js**

```
import {
  CASHING_AMOUNT_LIMIT,
  CASHING_DELETE_AMOUNT,
 } from '../appConfig';
 ...
export const reducer = handleActions({
  [REQUEST_DATA]: (state, action) => {
    if (payload.count >= CASHING_AMOUNT_LIMIT) {
      // do something with data if the condition is true
    }

    return {
      ...someState,
    };
  },
  ...
```

In my test, I want to change a value for `CASHING_AMOUNT_LIMIT` and check if reducer returns current store. And I don't know how to mock this variable in `reducer.js`. Here is my test:

```
...//imports
    const mockValues = {
      CASHING_AMOUNT_LIMIT: 10,
      CASHING_DELETE_AMOUNT: 5,
    };
    jest.mock('../../appConfig.js', () => mockValues);

    const {
      CASHING_AMOUNT_LIMIT,
      CASHING_DELETE_AMOUNT,
    } = require('../../appConfig.js');
...

  it('MY awesome test ', () => {

    expect(CASHING_AMOUNT_LIMIT).toBe(10);
    expect(CASHING_DELETE_AMOUNT).toBe(5); 


    // HERE is all ok CASHING_AMOUNT_LIMIT = 10 and the second variable is 5 
    //  tests are OK
    // ....


    expect(storeWithCache.dispatch(requestFunction({ test: 'XX'})))
    .toEqual(myStore);
    ...
```

In the end I use `dispatch` which call my reducer action and function in `reducer.js` it runs OK... but with old value for `CASHING_AMOUNT_LIMIT` it is still 50 (as in `appConfig.js`) and I need to set 10

Can somebody help me with mocking `CASHING_AMOUNT_LIMIT` in `reducer.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution we have all mock in one file `testenv.js` and it is importing globally I put `jest.mock('../../appConfig.js')` there and it works!

Answer (score 3):

This part

```
jest.mock('../../appConfig.js', () => mockValues);
```

Needs to be outside the describe block, under the imports.

Comment: the code you have in the example shows that it's inside of `it('MY awesome test ', () => {`. It should be outside at the very top of the file.

Comment: what is `storeWithCache`, and how do you import the reducer?

Comment: Why does it need to be outside the describe? Is there any solution to be able to use it inside describe block?

Comment: I don't think there is another way. Jest treats jest.mock as a special case by hoisting it. If you think about it, jest.mock needs to run before the imports/requires run. And that's only possible if we follow strict rules, such as those mocks should be at the top of the file (or after imports) and should not reference any variables (except for constants starting with mock).